# Rbx.Lua - Why won't this Color3 take in VertexColor?

Tags: for-loop, lua, parent-child, mesh, roblox

So I have a model that looks like this:

[image: Explorer]

There are Mesh objects under each pixel brick because this model uses the Mesh's VertexColor to color each pixel. I want to decrease this model's file size by getting rid of the VertexColor and replacing it with the Pixel Brick's BrickColor attribute. It will dramatically decrease color quality, but I just want to see what it comes up with.

So I came up with this, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work. If you replace line 4 with `.new(Color3.new(0.945, 0.941, 0.933))` it does it correctly. That is an actual number from one of the VertexColors btw.

```
local color = nil
for index, child in pairs(workspace.IMG:GetChildren()) do
    print(index, child.Name)
    color = child.Mesh.VertexColor
    child.BrickColor = BrickColor.new(Color3.new(color))
    child.Mesh:Remove()
end
```

So why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. I was supposed to do `Color3.new(color.X, color.Y, color.Z)` instead of `Color3.new(color)`.